# issue with the typeorm-model-generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, nestjs, typeorm

I have installed `typeorm-model-generator` without any problem, but when I type in terminal `typeorm-model-generator` I have an error

```
The term 'typeorm-model-generator' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or oper
able program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
 try again.
At line:1 char:24
+ typeorm-model-generator <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (typeorm-model-generator:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

if someone knows what's going on please answer

Comment: what exactly are you typing. just typeorm-model-generator. Obviously not. Please tell me exact command

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this command:
npm i -g typeorm-model-generator

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33150627)